# How to configure pylsp installed by Mason with lsp-zero for nvim?

Tags: neovim, lsp, whitespace, python, plugin

I want to disable a specific error/warning - E203.
[image: E203 example]

This is my `lsp.lua` where I tried to add ignore config according to this [doc from lsp-zero git](https://github.com/VonHeikemen/lsp-zero.nvim/blob/v3.x/doc/md/lsp.md#configure-language-servers)

```
local lsp = require("lsp-zero")

lsp.preset("recommended")


lsp.ensure_installed({
  'tsserver',
  'rust_analyzer',
})

-- Fix Undefined global 'vim'
lsp.nvim_workspace()


local cmp = require('cmp')
local cmp_select = {behavior = cmp.SelectBehavior.Select}
local cmp_mappings = lsp.defaults.cmp_mappings({
  ['<C-p>'] = cmp.mapping.select_prev_item(cmp_select),
  ['<C-n>'] = cmp.mapping.select_next_item(cmp_select),
  ['<C-y>'] = cmp.mapping.confirm({ select = true }),
  ["<C-Space>"] = cmp.mapping.complete(),
})

cmp_mappings['<Tab>'] = nil
cmp_mappings['<S-Tab>'] = nil

lsp.setup_nvim_cmp({
  mapping = cmp_mappings
})

lsp.set_preferences({
    suggest_lsp_servers = false,
    sign_icons = {
        error = 'E',
        warn = 'W',
        hint = 'H',
        info = 'I'
    },
})

lsp.on_attach(function(client, bufnr)
  local opts = {buffer = bufnr, remap = false}

  vim.keymap.set("n", "gd", function() vim.lsp.buf.definition() end, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", "K", function() vim.lsp.buf.hover() end, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>vws", function() vim.lsp.buf.workspace_symbol() end, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>vd", function() vim.diagnostic.open_float() end, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", "[d", function() vim.diagnostic.goto_next() end, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", "]d", function() vim.diagnostic.goto_prev() end, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>vca", function() vim.lsp.buf.code_action() end, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>vrr", function() vim.lsp.buf.references() end, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>vrn", function() vim.lsp.buf.rename() end, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("i", "<C-h>", function() vim.lsp.buf.signature_help() end, opts)
end)

lsp.setup()

vim.diagnostic.config({
    virtual_text = true
})

-- My attempt at disabling that whitespace warning
require('mason-lspconfig').setup({
  handlers = {
    lsp.setup(),
    pylsp = function()
        require('lspconfig').pylsp.setup({
            pylsp = {
                plugins = {
                    flake8 = {
                        ignore = {'E203'}
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    end,
  }
})
```

This made warning message disapper but for all errors (not only `E203`) and there is still `W` sign with underline on lines with error `E203`
[image: after]

This is what Mason is showing:
[image: mason]

Answer (score 0):

Check out
https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/39768/50207

```
require('mason-lspconfig').setup({
  handlers = {
    lsp.setup(),
    pylsp = function()
        require('lspconfig').pylsp.setup({
            pylsp = {
                pylps = {
                    plugins = {
                        flake8 = {
                            ignore = {'E203'}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    end,
  }
})
```